# Read-Only Config File in Android

Tags: android, configuration-files

I want to initialize Application From Config File. What Is the Best Way for creating read-Only file in android? I know Asset Folder is read-only . 
Here is My config Manager

### ConfigManager

```
public class ConfigManager {
    private static final String CONFIG_FILE         = "config";
    private static final String KEY_VALUE_SEPERATOR = "=";

    public static String loadConfig(Context context, String key) {
        List<String> lines = FileManager.readFromFile(context, CONFIG_FILE);
        Map<String, String> allConfig = parseLines(lines);
        return allConfig.get(key);
    }
    //For Writable Config File
    public static boolean saveConfig(Context context, Config config) {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        lines.add(config.key + KEY_VALUE_SEPERATOR + config.value);
        return FileManager.writeToFile(context, CONFIG_FILE, lines);
    }

    private static Map<String, String> parseLines(List<String> lines) {
        Map<String, String> out = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(String line : lines) {
            Config config = parseKeyAndValueFromLine(line);
            out.put(config.key, config.value);
        }
        return out;
    }

    private static Config parseKeyAndValueFromLine(String line) {
        Config out = new Config();
        int seperatorIdx = line.indexOf(KEY_VALUE_SEPERATOR);
        if(-1 == seperatorIdx) return out;
        String key = line.substring(0, seperatorIdx);
        out.key = key.trim();
        String value = line.substring(seperatorIdx + 1);
        out.value = value.trim();
        return out;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a properties file in assets directory; app.properties, for example. Then in code, you access like so:

```
try {
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("app.properties");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(inputStream);
    System.out.println("The properties are now loaded");
    System.out.println("properties: " + properties);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```